# Docker Alfresco share on port 80

Tags: docker, docker-compose, alfresco, nginx-reverse-proxy, alfresco-share

Trying to deploy alfresco community edition for production in docker environnement, i want to make share available on port 80.
In the default docker-compose.yml file i have modified in the declaration of nginx proxy :

```yaml
   services:
       alfresco:
           image: alfresco/alfresco-content-repository-community:7.1.0-A9
           mem_limit: 1500m
           environment:
               JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "
                   -Dencryption.keystore.type=JCEKS
                   -Dencryption.cipherAlgorithm=DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding
                   -Dencryption.keyAlgorithm=DESede
                   -Dencryption.keystore.location=/usr/local/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/keystore/keystore
                   -Dmetadata-keystore.password=mp6yc0UD9e
                   -Dmetadata-keystore.aliases=metadata
                   -Dmetadata-keystore.metadata.password=oKIWzVdEdA
                   -Dmetadata-keystore.metadata.algorithm=DESede
                   "
               JAVA_OPTS: "
                   -Ddb.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
                   -Ddb.username=alfresco
                   -Ddb.password=alfresco
                   -Ddb.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/alfresco
                   -Dsolr.host=solr6
                   -Dsolr.port=8983
                   -Dsolr.http.connection.timeout=1000
                   -Dsolr.secureComms=none
                   -Dsolr.base.url=/solr
                   -Dindex.subsystem.name=solr6
                   -Dshare.host=127.0.0.1
                   -Dshare.port=80
                   -Dalfresco.host=localhost
                   -Dalfresco.port=80
                   -Daos.baseUrlOverwrite=http://localhost:8080/alfresco/aos
                   -Dmessaging.broker.url=\"failover:(nio://activemq:61616)?timeout=3000&jms.useCompression=true\"
                   -Ddeployment.method=DOCKER_COMPOSE
                   -DlocalTransform.core-aio.url=http://transform-core-aio:8090/
                   -Dcsrf.filter.enabled=false
                   -XX:MinRAMPercentage=50 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80
                   "
   
           volumes:
               - alf-repo-data:/usr/local/tomcat/alf_data
               - alf-repo-logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs
               
       transform-core-aio:
           image: alfresco/alfresco-transform-core-aio:2.5.1
           mem_limit: 1536m
           environment:
               JAVA_OPTS: " -XX:MinRAMPercentage=50 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80"
           ports:
               - 8090:8090
   
       share:
           image: alfresco/alfresco-share:7.1.0-M2
           mem_limit: 1g
           environment:
               REPO_HOST: "alfresco"
               REPO_PORT: "8080"
               JAVA_OPTS: "
                   -XX:MinRAMPercentage=50
                   -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80
                   -Dalfresco.host=localhost
                   -Dalfresco.port=80
                   -Dalfresco.context=alfresco
                   -Dalfresco.protocol=http
                   "
           volumes:
               - alf-share-logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs
   
       postgres:
           image: postgres:13.1
           mem_limit: 512m
           environment:
               - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=alfresco
               - POSTGRES_USER=alfresco
               - POSTGRES_DB=alfresco
           command: postgres -c max_connections=300 -c log_min_messages=LOG
           ports:
               - 5432:5432
           volumes:
               - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
               - postgres-logs:/var/log/postgresql
               
       solr6:
           image: alfresco/alfresco-search-services:2.0.2
           mem_limit: 2g
           environment:
               #Solr needs to know how to register itself with Alfresco
               - SOLR_ALFRESCO_HOST=alfresco
               - SOLR_ALFRESCO_PORT=8080
               #Alfresco needs to know how to call solr
               - SOLR_SOLR_HOST=solr6
               - SOLR_SOLR_PORT=8983
               #Create the default alfresco and archive cores
               - SOLR_CREATE_ALFRESCO_DEFAULTS=alfresco,archive
               #HTTP by default
               - ALFRESCO_SECURE_COMMS=none
           ports:
               - 8083:8983 #Browser port
           volumes:
               - solr-data:/opt/alfresco-search-services/data
               
       activemq:
           image: alfresco/alfresco-activemq:5.16.1
           mem_limit: 1g
           ports:
               - 8161:8161 # Web Console
               - 5672:5672 # AMQP
               - 61616:61616 # OpenWire
               - 61613:61613 # STOMP
   
       proxy:
           image: alfresco/alfresco-acs-nginx:3.1.1
           mem_limit: 128m
           environment:
               DISABLE_PROMETHEUS: "true"
               DISABLE_SYNCSERVICE: "true"
               DISABLE_ADW: "true"
           depends_on:
               - alfresco
           ports:
               - 80:8080
           links:
               - alfresco
               - share
   volumes:
       alf-repo-data:
       alf-repo-logs:
       alf-share-logs:
       postgres-data:
       postgres-logs:
       solr-data:
```

When i try to reddirect ports 8080:80 like this, share does not load and i have 404 on my browser.

should i use a didacted apache server and use reverse proxy ?

After some tests i was able to access my alfresco share on port 80, but once i sign in with my credentials i got an error page on share/page/dologin:
[image]

Comment: What do you get when you run docker port alfresco/alfresco-acs-nginx:3.1.1

Comment: my docker-compose contain another declaration of all images necessary for alfresco to run. here is a docker-compose ps output :
.....................................................root_proxy_1                /entrypoint.sh                   Exit 255   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp,:::8080->8080/tcp
root_share_1                /usr/local/tomcat/shared/c ...   Exit 255   8000/tcp, 8080/tcp
root_solr6_1                /bin/sh -c $DIST_DIR/solr/ ...   Exit 255   10001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8083->8983/tcp,:::8083->8983/tcp...................

Comment: Maybe update your question with your full docker-compose.yml file

Answer (score 0):

```
 # This docker-compose file will spin up an ACS cluster on a local host or on a server and it requires a minimum of 13GB Memory to distribute among containers.
# Limit container memory and assign X percentage to JVM.  There are couple of ways to allocate JVM Memory for ACS Containers
# For example: 'JAVA_OPTS: "$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap"'
# See Oracle docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/gctuning/parallel-collector1.htm#JSGCT-GUID-CAB83393-3438-44ED-98F0-D15641B43C7D).
# If the container memory is not explicitly set then the flags above will set the max heap default to 1/4 of the container's memory, which may not be ideal.
# For performance tuning, assign the container memory and give a percentage of it to the JVM.

# Using version 2 as 3 does not support resource constraint options (cpu_*, mem_* limits) for non swarm mode in Compose
version: "2"

services:
  alfresco:
    image: alfresco/alfresco-content-repository-community:7.3.0-M2
    mem_limit: 1900m
    environment:
      JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "
        -Dencryption.keystore.type=JCEKS
        -Dencryption.cipherAlgorithm=DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding
        -Dencryption.keyAlgorithm=DESede
        -Dencryption.keystore.location=/usr/local/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/keystore/keystore
        -Dmetadata-keystore.password=mp6yc0UD9e
        -Dmetadata-keystore.aliases=metadata
        -Dmetadata-keystore.metadata.password=oKIWzVdEdA
        -Dmetadata-keystore.metadata.algorithm=DESede
        "
      JAVA_OPTS: "
        -Ddb.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
        -Ddb.username=alfresco
        -Ddb.password=alfresco
        -Ddb.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/alfresco
        -Dsolr.host=solr6
        -Dsolr.port=8983
        -Dsolr.http.connection.timeout=1000
        -Dsolr.secureComms=secret
        -Dsolr.sharedSecret=secret
        -Dsolr.base.url=/solr
        -Dindex.subsystem.name=solr6
        -Dshare.host=127.0.0.1
        -Dshare.port=8081
        -Dalfresco.host=localhost
        -Dalfresco.port=8080
        -Daos.baseUrlOverwrite=http://localhost:8080/alfresco/aos
        -Dmessaging.broker.url=\"failover:(nio://activemq:61616)?timeout=3000&jms.useCompression=true\"
        -Ddeployment.method=DOCKER_COMPOSE
        -DlocalTransform.core-aio.url=http://transform-core-aio:8090/
        -Dcsrf.filter.enabled=false
        -XX:MinRAMPercentage=50 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80
        "

  transform-core-aio:
    image: alfresco/alfresco-transform-core-aio:2.5.7
    mem_limit: 1536m
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: " -XX:MinRAMPercentage=50 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80"
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"

  share:
    image: alfresco/alfresco-share:7.3.0-M2
    mem_limit: 1g
    environment:
      REPO_HOST: "alfresco"
      REPO_PORT: "8080"
      JAVA_OPTS: "
        -XX:MinRAMPercentage=50
        -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80
        -Dalfresco.host=localhost
        -Dalfresco.port=8080
        -Dalfresco.context=alfresco
        -Dalfresco.protocol=http
        "
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.4
    mem_limit: 512m
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=alfresco
      - POSTGRES_USER=alfresco
      - POSTGRES_DB=alfresco
    command: postgres -c max_connections=300 -c log_min_messages=LOG
    ports:
      - "5532:5432"

  solr6:
    image: alfresco/alfresco-search-services:2.0.3
    mem_limit: 2g
    environment:
      # Solr needs to know how to register itself with Alfresco
      SOLR_ALFRESCO_HOST: "alfresco"
      SOLR_ALFRESCO_PORT: "8080"
      # Alfresco needs to know how to call solr
      SOLR_SOLR_HOST: "solr6"
      SOLR_SOLR_PORT: "8983"
      # Create the default alfresco and archive cores
      SOLR_CREATE_ALFRESCO_DEFAULTS: "alfresco,archive"
      # HTTPS or SECRET
      ALFRESCO_SECURE_COMMS: "secret"
      # SHARED SECRET VALUE
      JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "
          -Dalfresco.secureComms.secret=secret
      "
    ports:
      - "8083:8983" # Browser port

  activemq:
    image: alfresco/alfresco-activemq:5.17.1-jre11-rockylinux8
    mem_limit: 1g
    ports:
      - "8161:8161" # Web Console
      - "5672:5672" # AMQP
      - "61616:61616" # OpenWire
      - "61613:61613" # STOMP

  content-app:
    image: alfresco/alfresco-content-app:2.11.0
    mem_limit: 128m
    environment:
      APP_BASE_SHARE_URL: "http://localhost:8080/aca/#/preview/s"

  proxy:
    image: alfresco/alfresco-acs-nginx:3.4.2
    mem_limit: 128m
    environment:
      DISABLE_PROMETHEUS: "true"
      DISABLE_SYNCSERVICE: "true"
      DISABLE_ADW: "true"
      DISABLE_CONTROL_CENTER: "true"
      ENABLE_CONTENT_APP: "true"
    depends_on:
      - alfresco
      - content-app
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    links:
      - content-app
      - alfresco
      - share
```

I had the same problem but I think I partially solved it.

This links helped me to correctly change the ports : [alfresco docker share port change](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/alfresco-docker-share-port-change/m-p/292382#M16214)

But, I always have a problem when I want to access the api http://127.0.0.1:80/api-explorer/ by default I am always redirected to port 8080 while the api is on the port 80.